# How to print the values not the object IEnumerable<IEnumerable<>()>()

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, razor

I am trying to display the values of a list which is inside another list, but I am running into issues.

Here is the list containing values that I want to display:

```
"HotelAvailSideFilterResult": {
    "listaServices": [
      [
        {
          "code": "APCO",
          "description": "Aptos./Hab. con cocina",
          "font": null
        },
        {
```

So 2 things:

1. How do I print the `description` property using loops or whatever?
2. How do I query unique values?  I tried this but repeat values are returned:

```cs
var services = resultado.Hotels.Select(h => h.Features.Distinct());//LISTA DE SERVICIOS
var hotelTypes = resultado.Hotels.Select(h => h.Type.Distinct()).Distinct();//LISTA DE TIPOS DE HOTEL

model resultadoFiltro = new model() 
            {
                listaServices = services.ToList(), 
            };
```

Here are my models:

```cs
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<RS.Feature>> listaServices { get; set; }

public partial class Hotel
{


    public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }

}

public class Feature
{
    [JsonProperty("code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("font")]
    public string Font { get; set; }
}
```

Thank you very much

Comment: 1- var desc = listaServices.Select(x => x.description).toList
then a foreach over the desc ?
2- You could to over all and group them by the values you want, then decide based on the object within each group if they are unique or not and only select those (something like this (x=>x.Count ==1))

Comment: Can you show us valid json and Model where you want to perform these 2 operations

Comment: Maybe with SelectMany like `var services = resultado.Hotels.SelectMany(h => h.Features).Select(f => f.Description).Distinct();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the best way is this:

```cs
hotelAvailRS.Hotels.SelectMany(h => h.Features).ToList().GroupBy(f => f.Code).Select(f => f.First()).ToList()
```

Because you will have what you need and also later you will be able to use the property Code to bind when be required.

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Why are you doing a ToList() before your GroupBy?

Comment: Sorry complete right your point, there was no use to make a list which is already one. Could you take a look at this one if there is something wrong? looks okey but my head today is close to explote:               `var hotelMeals = resultado.Hotels.SelectMany(h => h.RoomGroups).SelectMany(i => i.Rates).Select( j => j.Meal).GroupBy( k => k.MapCode).Select( l => l.First()).ToList();`